# right way to do 3x column template

Tags: html, css, templates

I want to be sure that I'm doing the right thing for a relative 3-column design. Sidebars are limited by width.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <h1>left</h1>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <h1>left</h1>
</div>
<div id="center">
    <h1>center</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left { width:200px; height:200px; background:red; float:left; }
#right { width:200px; height:200px; background:blue; float:right; }
#center { margin:0 200px; background:orange; }
```

It works, but is this the right way to do it? Will there be any problems in the future with this HTML code?

Comment: One thing you can do differently is just name them all .third(or whatever you want to) and just put float left on it. They will all float next to each other and then just make sure to put a clear both on the parent container. This way just simplifies it a little bit and makes it easier to maintain down the road.

Answer (score 0):

you can use width: 33%; 
that way if the window changes size, the 3 columns will accommodate as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic question, but if you want to have a responsive width you can use percentage for width or height:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/aBwCJ/3/)

```
#right{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}
#left{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
#center{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:orange;
}
```

you can also use CSS frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).